# How to update a field with a new value using the REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, https, podio

I am using Podio and I want to be able to update items using the PODIO RESTful API.

I more specifically want to `PUT` plain text into an item field. I have successfully updated the field in question in accordance with the [instructions](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/update-item-field-values-22367). However the update results in updating the field with "no value". I cannot find out how to get the API to update the field with the value I provide. This is my code:

```
var path = '/item/';
var item_id = 346397274;
var value = 'value';
var field_id = 108976076;
var update = "foo"
var update_length = update.length;

var options = {
    'host': 'api.podio.com',
    'port': 443,
    'path': path + item_id + '/value/' + field_id,
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'method': 'PUT',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': update_length,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    }
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
})

req.write(update);
req.end();
```

I guess that my request body some how has to be different. But I have tried all kinds of combinations and I just can't get it to work. When I run a `GET` request the returned data for the field in question are as follows:

```
{ status: 'active',
  type: 'text',
  field_id: 108976076,
  label: 'Titel',
  values: [ { value: 'Old Value' } ],
  config: 
   { default_value: null,
     description: null,
     settings: { format: 'plain', size: 'small' },
     required: false,
     mapping: null,
     label: 'Titel',
     visible: true,
     delta: 0,
     hidden: false,
     unique: false },
  external_id: 'titel' }
```

I also tried putting the following in the request body: `var update = querystring.stringify({"value": "foo"});` and:

```
var update = {"values": [querystring.stringify({
    "value": "foo"
    })]
};

var update = querystring.stringify(update);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try following:

For request body:

```
{"titel": "My test value"}
```

For request url:

```
https://api.podio.com/item/<item_id>/value/
```

All together as cURL:

```
curl 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -H "Authorization: OAuth2 <access_token>" 
    -X PUT   
    -d '{"titel": "Some updates"}'
    https://api.podio.com/item/<item_id>/value/
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue seems to have been that I used `"Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. This worked for authentication purposes but apparently not for request purposes. Any ideas why?

Comment: May be because this request body is `json` and not `x-www-form` ?